# Setting up MongoLab or MongoHQ with Play Framework on Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, playframework

I can't seem to find any instructions for setting up either MongoHQ or MongoLab with Play Framework on Heroku.

Is there something similar to this which is for the Spring Framework (I believe) https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongohq#use-with-java that I can follow?

Or does anyone have any instructions that they can provide.

Answer (score 7):

MongoHQ adds a MONGOHQ_URL to your Heroku config environment

```
heroku config
```

Which returns something like

```
MONGOHQ_URL: mongodb://heroku:1234@someserver.mongohq.com:10071/app1234
```

Use this envronment variable inside your application to fetch which URI to connect Mongo to. I have an overriden property that can be specified in the Procfile

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=$PORT -Dmongodb.uri=$MONGOHQ_URL
```

And in a Play model class I connect and query Mongo with:

```
val mongoUri = MongoUri(Play.configuration.getString("mongodb.uri").get)

val mongoCollection = mongoUri.connectDB match {
  case Left(thrown) => throw thrown
  case Right(database) => {
    mongoUri.username.map { username =>
      mongoUri.password.map { password =>
        database.underlying.authenticate(username,password)
      }
    }
    database.apply("mycollection")
  }
}

def findSomething(something:String) = {
  val searchTerm = MongoDBObject("something" -> something)
  mongoCollection.findOne(searchTerm) map { mongoObject =>
    Logger.info("Found %s".format(mongoObject.getAs[String]("somethingElse")))
  }
}
```

Assumptions made: Play 2.0, Scala, [Casbah](https://github.com/mongodb/casbah)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example app that uses MongoHQ, Play 2, Scala, and works on Heroku:
https://github.com/jamesward/play2bars/tree/scala-mongodb

There aren't really instructions, just some simple code.